# How to validate a JSON object against a JSON schema without using JSchema nuget in c#?

Tags: c#, json

I want to validate JsonObject with JsonSchema, I'm using newtonsoft.json nuget, but which is saying that jsonschema is moved to its own path, then I used newtonsoft.json.schema nuget but which is paid version. is there any way to validate JSON object with jsonschema using login in c# can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
//using Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities



   var jsonobject = //your code to get json object
        var validjsonstring = Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSON.Validate(jsonobject);
        //code to parse etc..
```

Comment: what actually it validate, is it possible to validate data types in the schema? where to check JSON object with JSON schema?